# Some misunderstanding with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to figure out how XMLHttpRequest works.

HTML

```
<p>GET request: <span class="get">pending</span></p>
<p>POST request: <span class="post">pending</span></p>
<p>WEIRD request: <span class="weird">pending</span></p>
```

JS

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest(), 
    el, 
    resp, 
    handler;

function set(xhr, method, selector) {

    'use strict';

    handler = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            resp = xhr.responseText;
            el = document.querySelector(selector);
            el.innerHTML = JSON.parse(resp).status.toUpperCase();
            el.style.color = 'green';
            el.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        } else if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            el = document.querySelector(selector);
            el.innerHTML = 'Failed';
            el.style.color = 'red';
            el.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        }
    };

    xhr.open(method, 'https://cors-test.appspot.com/test', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
    xhr.send();
}

set(req, 'WEIRD', '.weird');
set(req, 'GET', '.get');
set(req, 'POST', '.post');
```

But I can't understand why it change only one element (need three). Any ideas why it sets style only for one element?

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send multiple requests from a single `XMLHttpRequest` instance.

You need a separate instance for each request.

Comment: Yes, now I see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> But I can't understand why it change only one element

For some odd reasons, your `req`, `el`, `resp` and `handler` variables are global; and you create only a single `XMLHttpRequest` object. For three requests, you will need three of them, so move your variables and initialisation inside the function (and those that should be local to the `handler` function, inside there)!

```
function set(xhr, method, selector) {
    'use strict';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    function handler() {
        var el = document.querySelector(selector);
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var resp = xhr.responseText;
                el.innerHTML = JSON.parse(resp).status.toUpperCase();
                el.style.color = 'green';
                el.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
            } else {
                el.innerHTML = 'Failed';
                el.style.color = 'red';
                el.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
            }
        }
    }

    xhr.open(method, 'https://cors-test.appspot.com/test', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
    xhr.send();
}
```